# How to edit a function on child theme?

Tags: php, wordpress, function, wordpress-theming

I've this function on `function.php`'s main theme:

```
if(!function_exists('eagle_booking_append_booking_button_menu') && eagle_booking_get_option('eagle_booking_header_button')):

    add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'eagle_booking_append_booking_button_menu', 12, 2 );

    function eagle_booking_append_booking_button_menu ( $items, $args ) {

        // BUTTON ACTION BASED ON BOOKING SYSTEM
        if (eagle_booking_get_option('booking_type') == 'builtin' ) {
          $eagle_booking_button_action  = eagle_booking_search_page();

        } elseif (eagle_booking_get_option('booking_type') == 'custom') {
          $eagle_booking_button_action = eagle_booking_get_option('booking_type_custom_action');

        } elseif (eagle_booking_get_option('booking_type') == 'booking') {
          $eagle_booking_button_action = eagle_booking_get_option('booking_type_booking_action');

        } elseif (eagle_booking_get_option('booking_type') == 'airbnb') {
          $eagle_booking_button_action = eagle_booking_get_option('booking_type_airbnb_action');

        } elseif (eagle_booking_get_option('booking_type') == 'tripadvisor') {
          $eagle_booking_button_action = eagle_booking_get_option('booking_type_tripadvisor_action');
        }

        if ((eagle_booking_get_option('eagle_booking_header_button')) && ( $args->theme_location == 'zante_main_menu' )) {
            $items .= '<li class="menu_button"><a href="'.$eagle_booking_button_action.'" class="button"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>'.esc_html__('BOOK ONLINE', 'eagle-booking').'</a></li>';
        }

        return $items;
    }

endif;
```

I'd like to edit the last part of the function, such as:

```
if ((eagle_booking_get_option('eagle_booking_header_button')) && ( $args->theme_location == 'zante_main_menu' )) {
    $mdpLinkButton = "/contact-us/";
    $items .= '<li class="menu_button"><a href="'.$mdpLinkButton.'" class="button"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>'.esc_html__('CONTACT US', 'eagle-booking').'</a></li>';
}
```

I've made the custom theme. But what should I do in that `function.php`? Override the above or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that first you need to remove the filter applied by the parent theme and then define it again in child theme as follows:

**Child Theme functions.php**

```
add_action( 'init', 'remove_my_action');
function remove_my_action() {
    remove_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'eagle_booking_append_booking_button_menu', 12 );
}

add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'child_eagle_booking_append_booking_button_menu', 12, 2 );

function child_eagle_booking_append_booking_button_menu ( $items, $args ) {

    // BUTTON ACTION BASED ON BOOKING SYSTEM
    if (eagle_booking_get_option('booking_type') == 'builtin' ) {
      $eagle_booking_button_action  = eagle_booking_search_page();

    } elseif (eagle_booking_get_option('booking_type') == 'custom') {
      $eagle_booking_button_action = eagle_booking_get_option('booking_type_custom_action');

    } elseif (eagle_booking_get_option('booking_type') == 'booking') {
      $eagle_booking_button_action = eagle_booking_get_option('booking_type_booking_action');

    } elseif (eagle_booking_get_option('booking_type') == 'airbnb') {
      $eagle_booking_button_action = eagle_booking_get_option('booking_type_airbnb_action');

    } elseif (eagle_booking_get_option('booking_type') == 'tripadvisor') {
      $eagle_booking_button_action = eagle_booking_get_option('booking_type_tripadvisor_action');
    }

    if ((eagle_booking_get_option('eagle_booking_header_button')) && ( $args->theme_location == 'zante_main_menu' )) {
$mdpLinkButton = "/contact-us/";
        $items .= '<li class="menu_button"><a href="'.$mdpLinkButton.'" class="button"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>'.esc_html__('CONTACT US', 'eagle-booking').'</a></li>';
    }

    return $items;
}
```

Comment: So I don't need to rewrite also `if(!function_exists('eagle_booking_append_booking_button_menu') && eagle_booking_get_option('eagle_booking_header_button'))`, right?

Answer (score 0):

The child theme functions.php is loaded before the parent theme functions.php, so If the parent theme function has the check `if ( ! function_exists() )` you can override it with the same function name in child functions.php